# In Jupyter Notebook, how to show output within function without using print

Tags: function, printing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

I want the code to show "123" without using built-in print function, but it does not. What should I do?

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

def myf():
    "123"
    
myf()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got right, you just want to print the "123", right?

```
def myf():
    print("123")
    
myf()
```

If you want to receive the "123" as a result of your def, would be something like this :

```
def myf():
    x = "123"
    return x
Z = myf()

print (Z)
```

> > > "123"

Comment: Thanks a lot, using print can do that. But you missed the condition "without using print" in the title of my question. I just have highlighted "without using built-in print function", too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display function:

[image]

Although, I don't think that's what you want. The settings you're enabling:

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Only apply to returned values; that's why you don't see it printed. If you return the value and call the function a few times, you'll see them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and let me know that there is `display` except `print`. However, what I want is showing variables inside the function without the help of any auxiliary function. Just like showing variables outside the function on Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to this, but I have some pointers to the problem.

Normal output is written either in stdout or stderr by some Python provided method. However, when utilizing the IPython feature of checking a value by using either direct value ("123") or variable (first line `a = "123"`, second line `a`). This output stream can not be captured with simple `%%capture` magic in Jupyter; the output vanishes in the scope of the function definition.

I do agree that this would be useful; in machine learning we sometimes use dependency inversion like structures, where we modify functions instead of line-by-line code, where debugging gets hard since we can not capture some of the outputs without injecting a print or display. However, not using display might have unwanted and hard to predict consequences as some of the models can be rather verbose in what they write. However, capturing some outputs without extra prints and displays from user defined cells might be nice feature.

Notice that sometimes print doesn't work, but display does. Print might not always understand how our utilities in pandas or matplotlib works.

Comment: Yeah, you just get my point. My original intention of asking this question is to find a more convenient way to display the value of a variable when debugging in a function on Jupyter Notebook.